# Should python unittest mock calls copy passed arguments by reference?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

The following code snippets were all run with `python 3.7.11`.

I came across some unexpected behavior with the `unittest.mock` `Mock` class. I wrote a unit test where a `Mock` was called with specific arguments to cover the case that the the real object, being mocked for, was expected to be called with during real runtime. The tests passed so I pushed a build to a real running device to discover a bug where not all of the arguments were being passed to the real object method. I quickly found my bug however to me it initially looked like my unit test should have failed when it instead succeeded. Below are some simplified examples of that situation. What I am curious about is if this behavior should be considered a bug or an error in understanding on my part.

```py
from `unittest.mock` import Mock

mock = Mock()
l = [1]
mock(l)

l.append(2)

mock.call_args
# Output: call([1,2]) 
# rather than call([1])

id(l) == id(mock.call_args[0][0])
# Output: True 
# This means the l object and latest call_args reference occupy the same space in memory
```

This copy by reference behavior is confusing because when a function is called in the same procedure, it is not expected that the function would be called with arguments appended to the object after the call.

```py
def print_var(x):
     print(x)

l = [1]
print_var(l)
# Output: 1

l.append(2)
# print_var never be called with [1,2]
```

Would it make sense for `call_args` to use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to emulate the behavior I was expecting?

Comment: No, it would be inefficient (and may not always work) to do that all of that time: https://bugs.python.org/issue32632. `mock.assert_called_once_with([1])` doesn't have that problem.

Comment: mock.assert_called_once_with([1]) would fail in the above example with output ```AssertionError: Expected call: mock([1])
Actual call: mock([1, 2])
```

Comment: The link you provided did help me find a solution thanks https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution on the [`unittest.mock` examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html)

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock
from copy import deepcopy
class CopyingMock(MagicMock):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        args = deepcopy(args)
        kwargs = deepcopy(kwargs)
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

c = CopyingMock(return_value=None)
arg = set()
c(arg)
arg.add(1)
c.assert_called_with(set())
c.assert_called_with(arg)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#    ...
# AssertionError: Expected call: mock({1})
# Actual call: mock(set())
```

Comment: or just `pip install copyingmock`